# configuration variables in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, configuration-files

I would like to offer configuration options for my sencha touch application, for instance a base URL (in order to make API calls).

Of course, this configuration should be in a file editable at deployment time.

Where is the right place to put this? A data store? Or should I just declare a namespace `MyApp.config` in a `config.js` file at the root and define variables and functions there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up defining a `MyApp.config` namespace and putting my stuff there

Answer (score 0):

I have placed a short code in the index.php (which is replacement for index.html) which was providing necessary configuration arguments in an array.

```
<script>
    my_settings={
        data:<?=$data?>,
    };
</script>
```

Other files were static to speed up loading time. My app.js was pulling data from global my_settings just fine.